# Unexpected arguments when running node script

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using Node v4.1.1 installed with nvm. I'm running a script from the command line, let's call this script test.js.

```
$ node test.js
```

When I inspect the arguments array, `process.argv`, I'm not seeing the commands that I passed in, `['node', 'test.js']`, but the entire path to the file `['/Users/JeffPowers/.nvm/versions/node/v4.1.1/bin/node', '/Users/JeffPowers/Development/.../test.js'']`.

Is this caused by a configuration issue, or is this something that should be expected in newer versions of Node.js?

Comment: Is it any different in older versions of node? `node` is just a variable corresponding to that path. process.argv corresponds to the actual executable, not the variable name. `var x = "123"; console.log(x);` is the same concept. EDIT: this is the default behavior in 0.12.5 and 0.10.30 as well.

Comment: That is the default behavior for me using node 4.0.0 (installed at system level on both Ubuntu and Mac OS X)

Comment: On windows 8, node 4.0 is showing me the full paths now too.  Apparently, that is now the behavior.

Comment: `An array containing the command line arguments. The first element will be 'node', the second element will be the name of the JavaScript file. The next elements will be any additional command line arguments.` from the doc

Comment: FYI I just tried the same thing with Node 4.1.2 in linux with similar results: argv has the full paths of both node and my test.js file.